CPanel Directory Privacy affects post requests
So I have website hosted on CPanel and I have a folder for PHP files that contain database logic. My public HTML files sends POST requests to obtain data. But I want to make the PHP folder private so that nobody except the admins can access it.
But when I visited my website I was immediately faced with a sign in popup which was meant to show up only when someone accesses the PHP folder.
I think it is because of the POST requests send from the home page to check whether the user is signed in.
What can I do to make the folder private but still be able to send POST requests from my other server files like login.html?
